# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2) - NSZombie not giving me anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a UITableview with custom cell to display a list from a web service. Code below:

```
#import "AgentEventsControllerViewController.h"
#import "EventCell.h"

@interface AgentEventsControllerViewController ()
{
  NSMutableData *webData;
  NSURLConnection *connection;
  NSMutableArray *myObject;
  // A dictionary object
  NSDictionary *dictionary;
  // Define keys
  NSString *EventID;
  NSString *Company;
  NSString *Summary;
}
@end

@implementation AgentEventsControllerViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSString *user = @"20";
  NSString *GetMe =@"JSON";
  NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyService?user=%@&GetMe=%@",user,GetMe];


  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

  if (connection)
  {
    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
  }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  return myObject.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
  EventCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.EventID_lbl.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:EventID]];
  cell.EventCompany_lbl.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:Company]];
  cell.EventSummary_lbl.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:Summary]];

  return cell;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  [webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

  EventID = @"Event";
  Company = @"Company";
  Summary = @"Summary";

  myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
  NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];


  for (NSDictionary *item in result) {

    NSString *company_data = item[@"company"];
    NSString *summary_data = item[@"summary"];
    NSString *eventID_data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event: %@", [item objectForKey:@"callref"]];

    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  eventID_data, EventID,
                  company_data, Company,
                  summary_data, Summary,
                  nil];
    [myObject addObject:dictionary];

  }


  [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

All appears to all be fine and printing out `tmpDict` to NSLog, I can see all the values I'd expect with nothing out of the ordinary. However, after a long pause during load the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2. I have enabled Zombies and run in profile but nothing is reported when the app crashes. As far as I can tell, the error appear to be happening on:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

But Xcode is giving nothing away as to what might be causing it. I am pretty new to Xcode so I am probably missing something glaringly obvious, but I can't see what.

Any help, greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the breakpoint navigator to set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.  When the app gets an error and enters the debugger, type "bt" at the (lldb) prompt in the debug console.  This gives a stack trace that's is frequently helpful in pointing at the problem.

Comment: QuartzCore`CA::Layer::ensure_transaction_recursively(CA::Transaction*) + 12, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8)

Then a whole load of ensure_transaction_recursively lines…

Infinite loop?

Comment: Side note: Replace lines like `cell.EventID_lbl.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:EventID]];` with `cell.EventID_lbl.text = tmpDict[EventID];`. There is no need to create a mutable string. There is no need for `stringWithFormat`, and use modern dictionary syntax. One last thing - follow standard naming conventions. Variable names should be camel case starting with lowercase letters.